# How to create a Node below a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{abstract}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=blue!40, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{comment}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=green, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{myarrow}=[->, >=open triangle 90, thick]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-, thick]
        
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (Item) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
        {
            \textbf{ITEM}
            \nodepart{second}name
        };
    \node (AuxNode01) [text width=4cm, below=of Item] {};
    \node (Component) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, left=of AuxNode01]
        {
            \textbf{COMPONENT}
            \nodepart{second}nil
        };
    \node (System) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, right=of AuxNode01]
        {
            \textbf{SYSTEM}
            \nodepart{second}parts
        };
   
    \draw[myarrow] (Component.north) -- ++(0,0.8) -| (Item.south);
    \draw[line] (Component.north) -- ++(0,0.8) -| (System.north);
        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I modified the example posted [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/class-diagram/).
The author put dummy node below "ITEM"   `\node (AuxNode01) [text width=4cm, below=of Item] {};` and created two nodes one to the right and one to the left.

Now my question is how to create a third node exactly below the item, at the place where the dummy node is. Intuitively I tried `at`  & `over` but did not work.

Comment: If you want another node at the same place where the dummy node is, why you not just use `below=of Item` again?

PS: Please use backticks `\`` for inline code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, the "at" is actually correct, but you put it at a different place:

```
\node (Blah) at (AuxNode01) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
    {
        \textbf{BLAH}
        \nodepart{second}parts
    };
```

For proper positioning, you should remove the `anchor=north` from the definition of the `abstract` style (I am not quite sure why it is there, anyway).

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

[image: flowchart]

In that case you can use `at (<node name>)`, and you need to use the option `anchor=center` for the new node, because it's set to `north` in a global option.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{abstract}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=blue!40, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{comment}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=green, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{myarrow}=[->, >=open triangle 90, thick]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-, thick]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (Item) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
        {
            \textbf{ITEM}
            \nodepart{second}name
        };
    \node (AuxNode01) [text width=4cm, below=of Item] {};
    \node (Component) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, left=of AuxNode01]
        {
            \textbf{COMPONENT}
            \nodepart{second}nil
        };
    \node (System) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, right=of AuxNode01]
        {
            \textbf{SYSTEM}
            \nodepart{second}parts
        };

    \node (New) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,anchor=center] at (AuxNode01)
        {
            \textbf{SYSTEM}
            \nodepart{second}parts
        };

    \draw[myarrow] (Component.north) -- ++(0,0.8) -| (Item.south);
    \draw[line] (Component.north) -- ++(0,0.8) -| (System.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes thats what I want to achieve. 'anchor=center' is what I am looking for